# Getting Form Values in MVC4 Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following html form which is being submitted by jQuery ajax.  I can't seem to understand how to grab the values from the input textbox's 'from inside my controller. I would have expected Request.Form["waitMinutes"] to work but it comes up null from within my controller.

What is the secret to getting the form values from within my controller?

```
<form method="post" action=@Url.Action("UpdateWaitTime", "Facilities")' data-ucw-updateWaitTimeForm="@facility.Id" style="display:none" >
    <input type="hidden" id='faciility' value="@facility.Id" />
    <input type="text" id="waitMinutes" value="0" style="width:15px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update Wait Time" />
    <span class="UpdateMessage"></span>
</form>
```

**My Jquery ajax submit code is:**

```
var ajaxUpdateWaitTime = function () {
        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        ...
        });
```

Comment: You need to give `name` attributes to your inputs... `<input type="text" id="waitMinutes" name="waitMinutes" value="0" style="width:15px" />`

Comment: That was it!!  Add this as an Answer and I'll mark you as answering it.  Thanks for the hand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send back your inputs' values to the server you need to give them a `name` (giving them an id is not enough).

From the [jQuery.serializable ducumentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (emphasis added by me)

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, **the element must have a name attribute**

So just give your inputs `name`s and it should work fine:

```
<form method="post" action=@Url.Action("UpdateWaitTime", "Facilities")' 
      data-ucw-updateWaitTimeForm="@facility.Id" style="display:none" >
    <input type="hidden" name='faciility' id='faciility' value="@facility.Id" />
    <input type="text" name="waitMinutes" id="waitMinutes" value="0" 
           style="width:15px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update Wait Time" />
    <span class="UpdateMessage"></span>
</form>
```